# How to subclass an Array in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to subclass `Array` to implement a `map` method that returns instances of my `Record` class. I'm trying to create a sort of "lazy" array that only instantiates objects as they are needed to try and avoid allocating too many Ruby objects at once. I'm hoping to make better use of the garbage collector by only instantiating an object on each iteration.

```
class LazyArray < Array
  def initialize(results)
    @results = results
  end

  def map(&block)
    record = Record.new(@results[i]) # how to get each item from @results for each iteration?
    # how do I pass the record instance to the block for each iteration?
  end
end

simple_array = [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}]
lazy_array_instance = LazyArray.new(simple_array)
expect(lazy_array_instance).to be_an Array
expect(lazy_array_instance).to respond_to :map
lazy_array_instance.map do |record|
  expect(record).to be_a Record
end
```

How can I subclass `Array` so that I can return an instance of my Record class in each iteration?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got?

Comment: @Makoto There's no code in the `map` method. Just comments.

Comment: It's not clear what semantics you want for your `map` method. Please edit your question to include some sample input and output.

Comment: @Andrew please clarify exactly what you're trying to achieve. The comments in your code don't necessarily explain what you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to create new `Record` instances as you iterate over results?

Comment: I'm assuming that you're trying to instantiate a new `Record` instance on for every item in your `@results` array? That's not necessarily lazy iteration or a lazy array.

Comment: I think you may wish to look at enumerators.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. @LeoCorrea is right. I'm trying to avoid creating and passing an array of Record instances. I'm trying to avoid allocating so many Ruby objects. I'm hoping to make better use of the garbage collector by only instantiating an object on each iteration.

Comment: Unfortunately, the question is still not clear--it should stand on its own without having to read the comments.

Comment: @WayneConrad I've re-worded my question to be more clear. Please re-open. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's clear enough now... thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So you have an array of simple attributes or some such and you want to instantiate an object before calling the `map` block. Sort of pre-processing on a value-by-value basis.

```
class Record
  attr_accessor :name
  def initialize(params={})
    self.name = params[:name]
  end
end

require 'delegate'
class MapEnhanced < SimpleDelegator
  def map(&block)
    @delegate_ds_obj.map do |attributes|
      object = Record.new(attributes)
      block.call(object)
    end
  end
end

array = MapEnhanced.new([{name: 'Joe'}, {name: 'Pete'}])

array.map {|record| record.name }
=> ["Joe" "Pete"]
```

An alternative (which will allow you to keep `object.is_a? Array`)

```
class MapEnhanced < Array
  alias_method :old_map, :map
  def map(&block)
    old_map do |attributes|
      object = Record.new(attributes)
      block.call(object)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hmm, this might work. However, I would no longer be subclassing an Array. I would not be able to use `MapEnhanced.new.is_a? Array`.

Comment: Ok, I've edited to include a version that is a subclass of Array.

Answer (score 1):

From what I know, you shouldn't have to do anything like this at all. Using [`.lazy`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator/Lazy.html) you can perform lazy evaluation of arrays:

```
simple_array_of_results.lazy.map do |record|
  # do something with Record instance
end
```

Now, you've got some odd situation where you're doing something like -

```
SomeOperation(simple_array_of_results)
```

and either you want `SomeOperation` to do it's thing lazily, or you want the output to be something lazy -

```
lazily_transformed_array_of_results = SomeOperation(simple_array_of_results)
page_of_results = lazily_transformed_array_of_results.take(10)
```

If that sounds right... I'd expect it to be as simple as:

```
SomeOperation(simple_array_of_results.lazy)
```

Does that work? `array.lazy` returns an object that responds to `map`, after all...

Edit:
...after reading your question again, it seems like what you actually want is something like:

```
SomeOperation(simple_array_of_results.lazy.collect{|r| SomeTransform(r)})
```

`SomeTransform` is whatever you're thinking of that takes that initial data and uses it to create your objects ("as needed" becoming "one at a time"). `SomeOperation` is whatever it is that needs to be passed something that responds to `map`.